Spark Sql or Pyspark to convert one specific row to column
Trying to convert one specific row of a table to column. Tried pivot logics and its not working for specific row value.
Input :
col1 col2 col3  col4
a     b   abc    0 
a     b   total  9 
e     r   uty    5 
e     r   total  44 
w     v   xtr    3

output
col1 col2 col3  col4  total
a     b   abc    0     9
e     r   uty    5     44
w     v   xtr    3     0

total in col3 as row values has to be converted into column. is there any functions can be applied instead of join logic using Pyspark or Spark sql ?

This does not look like a Pivot use case.
This is what you can do instead.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Filter out rows where col3 is 'total'
df_with_no_total = df.filter(F.col("col3") != "total")

# Filter rows where col3 is 'total' and rename col3 to 'total'
df_with_total = df.filter(F.col("col3") == "total").withColumnRenamed("col3", "total")

# Perform inner join on the 'col1' column
result_df = df_with_no_total.join(df_with_total, on="col1", how="inner")

# Select only the columns from df_with_no_total and the 'total' column from df_with_total
final_result_df = result_df.select(df_with_no_total["*"], df_with_total["total"])

# Show the result
final_result_df.show()


Create a standard pivot table with key columns col1 and col2 and then transform the the unwanted columns back into col3 and col4.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ...

# create the pivot table
df2=df.groupBy('col1', 'col2').pivot('col3').max('col4')

# get the list of columns to be merged
cols=list(set(df2.columns) - set(['col1', 'col2', 'total']))

# create a sql statement that puts the non-null column into a struct
stmt = "case "
for c in cols:
    stmt = f"{stmt} when not {c} is null then named_struct('name', '{c}', 'val', {c}) "
stmt = f"{stmt} end"

# generate col3 and col4 from the temporary column
df2 \
    .withColumn('tmp', F.expr(stmt)) \
    .withColumn('col3', F.col('tmp.name')) \
    .withColumn('col4', F.col('tmp.val')) \
    .drop('tmp') \
    .drop(*cols) \
    .show()


This approach works only when all combinations of col1, col2 and col3  are unique.
